# Elasticsearch: Aggregate only over the n most relevant search results

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run an aggregation over a very small subset of documents. The subset should comprise only those documents whose domCompleteTime field value matches, or closely matches a supplied value.

The closest I've got is aggregating over documents matching a narrow range (see below) but the query is not dependable because the number of document hits can range from zero to 100+.

What I really want is to rewrite the query to always aggregate over the 5 closest matches. The closest I've found in the es docs is `top_hits` but AFAICT that seems to only work over groups, which is not what I'm looking for here.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "params": {
                    "matchValue": "32562"
                  },
                  "inline": "(Math.abs(matchValue - doc['domCompleteTime'].value) < (matchValue/1000))"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "domParseEnd": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "domParseEnd",
        "percents": [50]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For starters, to reference the parameter you need to use params.matchValue

Comment: The above query is working.